# Fragments and Broadcast Receivers

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-fragments

I have an `activity` with two `fragments`. I am not using `<fragment/>` tags, I have two classes that extends `Fragment`, in that fragment, I have:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.bfragment, container, false); // this will inflate the Fragment in activity.
    }
```

Now the problem is, I am receiving some broadcast receivers in activity from which some receivers update the UI from first fragment and some updates the UI from 2nd.

One of my broadcast receiver defined in my main acitivity is:

```
private BroadcastReceiver bcReceived = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("", "BC Object Received");

            ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
            actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            ActionBar.Tab bTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("B");
            Fragment fragment = new BFragment();
            bTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(fragment));
            actionbar.addTab(bTab, true);

            final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bTable);  // Getting null pointer exception here. linearLayout is not getting initialized.
```

I want to use the above linearLayout and use it to inflate a view in it. But getting NPE.

here, when some broadcast receivers update the first fragment, it works properly, but when a broadcast receiver updates the 2nd fragment from activity, I get NPE.

**My question is:** How and where should I update the fragment? Should it be inside my activity? if yes then in which method? if not then where should I update the fragment?

Please help me!!!

Comment: The layout (R.layout.bfragment) is the same for the two fragments ? Does R.id.bTable is present in both fragments or not ?

Comment: if you are asking if both layouts looks similar then no. But both layouts gets inflated in same container by replacing the previous layout.

Comment: R.id.bTable is your container right ?

Comment: No. bFragment is my container. And R.id.bTable is a linearLayout inside this container.

Comment: You may find a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835523/update-fragment-ui-based-off-of-activitys-broadcast-receiver/24921134#24921134).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your activity logic should be separated from your fragments logic.

Your activity is supposed to handle the logic like:

> I need to display this fragment instead of that one

But your activity is **not** supposed to handle this kind of logic:

> I need to update what's inside the fragment

It is the responsability of the fragment to update it's content.
On the other hand, the activity may tell the fragment that it needs to update itself.

With that in mind, your fragments should expose methods like

```
updateContent(With Blabla)
```

OR

```
updateContent()
```

In your activity, when the `BroadcastReceiver` receives something you should:

- Check which fragment is currently displayed
- Prepare the content to update in the fragment
- Ask the fragment to update with the `updateContent(With Blabla)` method.

OR

- Check which fragment is currently displayed
- Ask the fragment to update itself with the `updateContent()` method.

Chose the most simple method according to your application business logic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Timothée Jeannin. Let me implement it this way.

Comment: No problem, feel free to ask if you need more explanations. Good luck with your project. :)

Comment: Can you tell me, how to check which fragment is currently attached to my activity?

Comment: As i understood, you're not using the <Fragment /> tag in the xml ressources. Then i guess your activity is responsible for creating the fragments. You could keep a reference to the displayed fragment in your activity and use the "instanceof" java keyword to find wich fragment is currently displayed. Make sure the field is declared as the super class. (Fragment currentFragment) NOT (MyCustomFragment currentFragment)

Comment: Yeah! Am bit confused. I have used Fragment fragment = new BFragment(); but this doesn't mean that the onCreateView() will get called from Fragment. So when does onCreateView() gets called?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html You could check here to know when the onCreateView is called.

Comment: I think you should use : if(fragment instanceof MyCustomFragment)

Comment: Can you tell me, how to make sure that all the broadcast receivers are received? or after receiving onReceive() of broadcast receiver, which method in activity life cycle is called?

Comment: I think there isn't any specific activity life cycle method called after receiving a broadcast. The broadcast onReceive method is not tied to your activity.

Comment: About making sure you received the broadcast, i don't really know if there is a way to monitor that. But if the Intent that triggers the broadcast is allaways the same and the Broadcast worked at least once, i would say that it works for all of them ...