# update fragment ui based off of Activity's Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, android-service

First let me say I have read through many of the questions related to fragments on SO.  However, I can't seem to find a situation quite the same as mine.

I have myActivity that is using the PageAdapter, each page being a fragment.  I also have a service that receives updates about the network connections etc.  The service triggers the receiver in myActivity.  myActivity needs to update FragmentPage1 but because I am using a pageAdapter and creating my fragments at run time I cannot 'findFragmentbyId' etc.  I do not need to pass any data I just need to trigger the function inside of the FragmentPage1 class.  Please see code snippet below.

```
public class myActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(fm);
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

    // add tabs. Use ActionBar for 3.0 and above, otherwise use TabWidget
    final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    bar.addTab(bar.newTab()
            .setText(R.string.fragment_page_1)
            .setTabListener(new ActionBarTabListener(mPager)));
    bar.addTab(bar.newTab()
            .setText(R.string.fragment_page_2)
            .setTabListener(new ActionBarTabListener(mPager)));

     private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent){
                 if(intent.getAction().equals(InterfaceManager.BROADCAST_UPDATE_CONNECTION_STATS)) { 
                     updateFragmentPage2();
                 } else if (intent.getAction().equals(InterfaceManager.BROADCAST_UPDATE_RULES)) {
                     UpdateFragmentPage1();
                 }
            }
     };
}


public class FragmentPage2 extends Fragment implements OnCheckedChangeListener, OnClickListener  {
    public void UpdateFragmentPage2() {
        //update list view
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code, Here's what you can do quickly.

```
int tabIndex = 0;
MyCustomFragment frag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getActionBar().getTabAt(tabIndex).getText().toString());
frag.updateFragmentContent();
```

Create a custom base fragment MyCustomFragment and have an abstract method updateFragmentContent(), then you'd just need to change the tab index and no special typecast

Please note, The above is a cleaner way to do it. With your existing code, you can still have two separate type cast and call two separate methods to update corresponding fragments.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So when I try your code above it always returns null for the frag.  After extrapolating the pieces in the parameter list, it is failing on the getText().toString() part, I am able to get the fm and the actionBar.tab.    Also, can you elaborate on the other part of your suggestion of using a base fragment with an abstract method.  Won't that introduce the same problem but just at the base fragment class level?

Comment: getTab().getText() should return you the title text for the choosen Tab, Since you are setting the tab titles correctly, I don't really know, what could be wrong in retrieving it back.  Have you tried stepping through the debugger, to see what is the text associated with the tag. It might be because you are using a resource id to set the tab text. Alternatively, you could do a tab.setTag() and tab.getTag() to achieve the same results.

Comment: Thanks!  just had to add .setTag() to declaration!

Answer (score 1):

Due to the complex communication between the `BroadcastReceiver`, `Fragment` and `Activity`, I faced a similar problem and chose to slip out of that twist, and used the following:

When the `BroadcastReceiver` `onReceive()` method gets called add a `boolean` to the `SharedPreferences` as an indication flag that the Fragment should do something, and in the fragments `onResume()` method do the needed logic based on the `SharedPreferences` `boolean` set in the `BroadcastReceiver` `onReceive()` method.

Be informed though that there are better practices, and that **I did not test such an approach on a long running term application.**

Comment: could you please mention some of those other better approaches?